# How can i optimise my code with BufferedInputStream

Tags: java, fileinputstream, bufferedinputstream

Suppose I have an InputStream that contains text data, and I want to detect all words and their numLine.
this is my code:

```
try {
  BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(filePath));
  int currentChar;
  int numLine = 1;
  StringBuilder word = new StringBuilder();
  while ((currentChar = bis.read()) != -1) {
    if ((char) currentChar == '\n') {
      numLine++;
    }

    if (Character.isLetter((char) currentChar)) {
      word.append((char) currentChar);
    }
    if (!Character.isLetter((char) currentChar) || bis.available() == 0) {
      if (word.length() > 0) {
        mapAllWordsPositionInFilesInFolder
            .computeIfAbsent(word.toString(), v -> new HashMap<>())
            .computeIfAbsent(filePath, val -> new HashSet<>())
            .add(numLine);
      }
      word = new StringBuilder();
    }
  }
  bis.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Please someone can help to otimise my code! thank's.

Comment: Optimize how?  Speed?  Memory?  Code size?  Coding style (hint -- it's terribly formatted and not very easy to read)?  You might do better on CodeReview, if this code works and you just want it be -- somehow -- better.

Comment: Coding style ! yes i know it's very bad ! :(

Comment: Then fix it.  The easier it is for people to read, the more substantive suggestions you might get.  Again, CodeReview might be a better place.  Check it out.

Comment: @TomServo fyi, if you write `[codereview.se]`, it links to [codereview.se].

Comment: @AndyTurner Yeah I know.  And if OP can't find it then that's a different problem.

Comment: @TomServo if you didn't know that Code Review is a stackexchange site, how would you find it? Type "CodeReview" into a search engine? [codereview.se] does come up as the first result for me; but I'd assume you meant something different, because of the spacing. Or maybe you did mean that...? Help a beginner out, give them the link.

Comment: And for logic ! it's good ? some one has more idea ?

Comment: @Orland there are things like the fact you don't close the stream (use try-with-resources); you don't need to keep casting to `char`; you probably shouldn't use `bis.available()`; you don't need to create a new `StringBuilder`, you could just clear it. But, again, head over to [codereview.se] to get a thorough answer.